# Why do the landing gears of Boeing 767 and certain Airbus aircraft tilt down?

Tags: landing-gear, airbus, boeing-767

[image: Example of the 767's gear tilt.]

I need help and some explanation on why are they sometimes tilted down instead of up.

Comment: Hopefully the linked duplicate (being the opposite of this question) answers this question.